# What's wrong in my code?

Tags: swift2

```
let interestingNumbers = {
            "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
            "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8],
            "Square": [1,4,9,16,25],
        }
        var largest = 0
        var largestKind = "Prime"
        for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
            var isThisKindLargest = false
            for number in numbers{
                if number > largest {
                    largest = number
                    isThisKindLargest = true
                }
            }
            if isThisKindLargest {
                largestKind = kind
            }
        }
        print(largest)
        print(largestKind)
```

Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' this error is given by Xcode-beta 7.1

Answer (score 5):

A dictionary is created using square brackets: `[` and `]`.

```
let interestingNumbers = [
   "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
   "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8],
   "Square": [1,4,9,16,25]
]
```